# Use a System.Drawing.Printing.PrintDocument to generate a PDF in memory

Tags: c#, asp.net, pdf

Does anyone know if the following is possible and if so what the best way of doing it is for free?

I am generating a PrintDocument in a project I am currently working on and displaying a print dialog box so a user can choose which printer they want to use etc. The is currently a windows form application and if a user wants to print to a PDF they can select to print to CutePDF or something similar.

However I am now putting a ASP.Net web frontend on the application and want to use the same code to generate the PrintDocument but want to print it to a PDF on the fly and serve it up via the Response stream in the format of a PDF download.

So my question is....How can I use the current PrintDocument and generate a PDF in memory from it??

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The System.Drawing code for a PrintDocument can be reused to generate a PDF document with ABCpdf .NET.  See the [System.Drawing example...](http://www.websupergoo.com/helppdf7net/source/4-examples/20-systemdrawing.htm)

Answer (score 0):

You would have to use a 3rd party component in order to generate the PDF.  The following article has some links to some such components: [Generating PDF Files from .Net](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1109412/generating-pdf-files-from-net-by-using-standard-net-gdi-printing-classes)

Answer (score 0):

You're in a world of hurt if you think you're going to run the "same code" that deals with printers in both a forms app and an ASP.NET app.

You might be in luck, however, as it appears that [PDFsharp + MigraDoc](http://www.pdfsharp.net/wiki/DocumentViewer-sample.ashx) might be able to do this for you.

Answer (score 0):

I think you will find there is not any tools that will take a PrintDocument as input and render a PDF as output. The only way to do what you want is to "print" the PrintDocument to a "PDF printer driver" that will generate PDF. Basically a virtual printer that will generate PDF instead of printing the actual output. There are a plethora of products on the market for that. A couple that are cheap and widely used are as follows:

- [Ghostscript with RedMon](http://pages.cs.wisc.edu/~ghost/redmon/en/redmon.htm#274) (open source/GPL or commercial licenses available)
- [Foxit Software's PDF Creator](http://www.foxitsoftware.com/pdf/creator/) ($29)

Answer (score 0):

You really should be looking at iTextSharp (it is mentioned on the iText.NET page recommended earlier)

http://itextsharp.sourceforge.net/

PrintDocument is meant for Windows Forms applications but is up and coming in SilverLight, see this video... http://silverlight.net/learn/videos/all/printing-api-basics/

If you wish to continue with the PrintDocument and a web application, I think SilverLight 4 (which is beta right now) is the only way to go, or your going to have to have a lite weight windows form application installed locally for the end user that maybe uses web services.

iTextSharp is a great tool for generating PDFs with .NET on the Internet.  I highly recommend it; I've used iText with Java...and have been using iTextSharp for the past few years.

Answer (score -1):

There are several ports of iText for .NET (A very popular open-source PDF library for Java).

http://www.ujihara.jp/iTextdotNET/en/