# C# tool for printing into PDF which is compatible with Graphics class

Tags: c#, pdf, printing

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Use a System.Drawing.Printing.PrintDocument to generate a PDF in memory](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2002025/use-a-system-drawing-printing-printdocument-to-generate-a-pdf-in-memory)

I wrote a vast amount of code which prints reports. All printing is done using System.Drawing.Printing and System.Drawing namespaces. But now I faced a problem to print all the same things into pdf file. I cannot use PDF printer and want to use a tool to print to PDF straight. After googling a while I found no suitable tool which I can use to print easily to PDF and using capabilities of .NET classes like System.Drawing. So my question is does anybody know such a tool which somehow translates invocations of System.Drawing namespace functions(like the ones in Graphics class) or my best bet it to pick a printing tool and rewrite my code using functions which available in printing tool?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Look here: [Use a System.Drawing.Printing.PrintDocument to generate a PDF in memory](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2002025/use-a-system-drawing-printing-printdocument-to-generate-a-pdf-in-memory)