# How to save PrinterDocument values in pdf without asking any save dialog box . already path will be defined in vb.net

Tags: vb.net, pdf

> PrintDoc.DocumentName = "PDFFILE"
>   PrintDoc.PrinterSettings.PrinterName = "Foxit PDF Printer"
>   PrintDoc.PrinterSettings.PrintFileName = "c:\PDFFILE.pdf"
>   PrintDoc.Print()

i need to save PDF automatically in defined path in Vb.net without asking any save dialog box or is there any other tools or dll etc

Comment: Have you tried looking up the `Save` methods available?

Comment: Yes code I  mentioned on top this what I tried . it should done in back end without any messages

Comment: Yep, and none of those looks like a `save` method...

Comment: Sorry i don't know i think this is save method can please tell me save method. i want to store in back end with any message or save dialog box @Dave

Comment: Read through this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1109412/generating-pdf-files-from-net-by-using-standard-net-gdi-printing-classes

Comment: In this it is asking dialogue box for save the pdf

Comment: Top answer has a link that gives some details of how to make it happen: http://www.websupergoo.com/helppdfnet/source/4-examples/20-systemdrawing.htm